# Error opening nautilus

Tags: nautilus

I get the following error when I try to open nautilus:
`(nautilus:4189): WARNING **: 11:18:17.052: Unable to get contents of the bookmarks file: Error opening file /root/.gtk-bookmarks: No such file or directory.`  Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you running it as root or ran it as root previously?

Comment: Run it with SUDO

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I did not use sudo.

Comment: I'm pretty sure @Itra is just kidding, of course do not run file manager or anything else as a root, you gonna mess up permissions; well, judging by the error you already did. Try executing `mv ~/.config/nautilus{,BCKP}`, and see if that helps.